# Preg_match_all split multiple occurrences

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string like this:

`string="59|https://site59.com20|https://site20.com30|https://site30.com16|https://site15.com66|https://site66.com29|https://site29.com";`
    -Just one example is not just that.
I did this regular expression
`preg_match_all("/[0-9][0-9](?:\|)(?:https\:\/\/)(.*?)/", string, string2);`

But it only takes `number|https:`

I wonder how do I get it and only stop when you find the next occurrence of the regular expression and separate it into different arrays

Comment: just explode() on the pipe

Comment: What is the result you want to have? As @nogad says,  `explode('|', "59|https://site59.com20|https://site20.com30|https://site30.com16|https://site15.com66|https://site66.com29|https://site29.com")` will do what you want I presume

Comment: I simplified case. But there are other complications which does not allow the use of explode. I have to separate using regular expression.

Comment: @FernandRoyale what output do you want from the input string you provided?

Comment: Personally, I'd use a much more simple regex like `/\d{2}\|https:\/\//` but preg_split is what you want.

Comment: well how can one suggest an answer if you dont provide an accurate description (example) of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string="59|https://site59.com20|https://site20.com30|https://site30.com16|https://site15.com66|https://site66.com29|https://site29.com";
preg_match_all("/(?:[0-9][0-9](?:\|)(?:https\:\/\/)(.*?)(?=[\d][\d]\||$))|([\d][\d]\|.*)/", $string, $matches);
```

Results array in $matches:

```
[0] => 59|https://site59.com
[1] => 20|https://site20.com
[2] => 30|https://site30.com
[3] => 16|https://site15.com
[4] => 66|https://site66.com
[5] => 29|https://site29.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
<?php

$string="59|https://site59.com20|https://site20.com30|https://site30.com16|https://site15.com66|https://site66.com29|https://site29.com";

$sites = preg_split("/[0-9][0-9](?:\|)(?:https\:\/\/)(.*?)/", $string);

foreach($sites as $site){
    echo "https://$site\n";
}
```

> ```
> https://site59.com
> https://site20.com
> https://site30.com
> https://site15.com
> https://site66.com
> https://site29.com
> ```